# Redirect entire sub directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a wordpress site that was hacked and has thousands of links that I want to redirect to the home page.

Here is what I have put in my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^scategory/(.*)  http://www.truckeeriverrock.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^whosonline/(.*)  http://www.truckeeriverrock.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^admintools/(.*)  http://www.truckeeriverrock.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The problem is that google search console is still showing some of these errors. For example if I go to
http://www.truckeeriverrock.com/whosonline/ it gets redirected according to the htaccess rules above.
But...
If I go to: http://www.truckeeriverrock.com/whosonline/srfudw/sriktgajxl.cfm
I fet redirected to: http://www.truckeeriverrock.com/srfudw/sriktgajxl.cfm (which shows a 404 page).

How can I make sure that absolutely anything in the whosonline directory and below gets redirected to the home page?

UPDATE:
Per responses I changed the 3 lines of code to the following but the redirect is still not working how I want it to.

```
RewriteRule ^(scategory|whosonline|admintools)/ http://www.truckeeriverrock.com/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^(scategory|whosonline|admintools)/ http://www.truckeeriverrock.com/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

Instead of your 3 lines.

Comment: Thanks, still have the same redirect problem but like the idea of compressing the code.

Comment: That can't be the same problem, with my code. Try to clear your cache or with other browser.

Comment: You were right! I put it in an incognito window and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if you simply want to always redirect to the homepage, you should drop the "$1" at the end of each rewrite destination. That $1 serves as a variable based on the matching pattern from the search URL. Thus it's trying to append the erroneous subdirectory information to the end of your website address.

Just try it without those $1's and let us know how it works.

Comment: I tried this and get the same results. The sub-directory of the sub-directory /whosonline/ doesn't redirect to the home page.

Comment: Just messed with this a bit this morning -- sometimes those rewrite rules seem to get cached in your browser for some reason. Can you try this from a new browser or from incognito mode?